# Is hasRemaining() method really necessary while reading from the source channel of Pipe object?

Tags: java, buffer, nio

The `hasRemaining()` method of the `ByteBuffer` class in java.nio package returns whether there are any elements between the current position and the limit.

At the same time, the documentation of the `write()` method of `FileChannel` class says:

> An attempt is made to write up to `r` bytes to the channel, where `r` is the number of bytes remaining in the buffer, that is, `src.remaining()`, at the moment this method is invoked.

This is my main method where I am using a sink channel and source channel of pipes in java NIO:

```
try {
            Pipe pipe = Pipe.open();
            Runnable writer = () -> {
                try {
                    Pipe.SinkChannel sinkChannel = pipe.sink();
                    ByteBuffer writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        String currentTime = "The current time is " + System.currentTimeMillis();
                        writeBuffer.put(currentTime.getBytes());
                        writeBuffer.flip();

                        while (writeBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                            int writtenBytes = sinkChannel.write(writeBuffer);
                            System.out.println("Channel is writing " + writtenBytes + " bytes");
                        }

                        writeBuffer.flip();
                        Thread.sleep(150);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };

            Runnable reader = () -> {
                try {
                    Pipe.SourceChannel sourceChannel = pipe.source();
                    ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        int bytesRead = sourceChannel.read(readBuffer); 
                        byte[] stringRead = new byte[bytesRead];

                        readBuffer.flip();
                        readBuffer.get(stringRead);
                        readBuffer.flip();

                        System.out.println("Buffer reading '" + new String(stringRead) + "'");
                        Thread.sleep(150);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };

            new Thread(writer).start();
            new Thread(reader).start();

} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I would like to know if the `hasRemaining()` method is really mandatory or not and when should I use it.

Comment: Why should the documentation of **FileChannel** have relevance for the **Pipe.SinkChannel**? On the other hand, you didn’t cite the FileChannel’s documentation, contrary to what you said. When you read [`WritableByteChannel.write`’s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/WritableByteChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer)) *completely*, you may notice that it says: “*Some types of channels, depending upon their state, may write only some of the bytes or possibly none at all.*”

Comment: So does the sinkChannel write all the remaining bytes or not ?

Comment: That doesn’t mean that you always need a `while (writeBuffer.hasRemaining()) { … }` loop. If you implement the loop correctly, i.e. using [`compact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#compact()) instead of `flip` after the write, there’s no problem if not all bytes have been written. In your case, you have to skip the `writeBuffer.put(currentTime.getBytes())` if there is not enough remaining space (which would implicitly write again).

Comment: Since the documentation of `SinkChannel` does not specify anything, I’d not assume that it makes any guarantees. But why should it matter? If you implement the loop correctly, there’s no harm.

Comment: Your code is wrong. After `flip()` and `get()`, or `flip()` and `write()`, you should call `compact()`, not another `flip()`. You only need the `hasRemaining()` loop if the channel is in non-blocking mode, but in that case you still shouldn't loop, you should use a `Selector` to tell you when the channel becomes writable again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating a little deeper I found that the abstract class `SinkChannel` that is a part of the class `Pipe` is implemented by a class named `SinkChannelImpl`.

In the latter class, a `SocketChannel` object is used as a channel, and the write method is implemented in the `SocketChannelImpl` class since
`SocketChannel` is an abstract class too.

Bottom line is that when I call the `write()` method of the `SinkChannel` I am actually calling the `write()` method of the `SocketChannelImpl` class.

Unfortunately, the documentation does not really specify if all of the remaining bytes will be written to the channel or not, quote:

> Some types of channels, depending upon their state, may write only some of the bytes or possibly none at all

Also the code is obfuscated and will take some time to know how it works.

So I will be using the `compact()` method after the write so in case some of the bytes are not written they will be moved to the beginning of the buffer.